# Ajax loading Json with time interval and media to show on fullscreen page

Tags: php, json, ajax, xml

I' know the title sounds a bit strange, I'm new with Ajax.
I have created a backend manager where I can upload files and pictures and creates a json file like this.

```
{
"time":"10",
"type":"video",
"media":"demo.mp4"
} 
{
"time":"5",
"type":"pic",
"media":"splash.jpg"
}
```

What I can't do is to create a landingpage with a script that loads the json and shows me for 10 seconds demo.mp4 inside a:

```
<video loop muted autoplay class="fullscreen-bg__video">
    <source src="demo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

After that for 5 seconds splash.jpg and so on.

```
<div class="fixed-background">
    <img src="media/splash.jpg" class="myimg" />
</div>
```

When the json array schedule is finished it reloads the json file and so on.
I don't know if it is possible in this way with Ajax and Json.

I'm sorry about the question but It's my second day trying to get the job done without success.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely possible. You're going to want to use `window.setInterval(callback, time)`. That will call the callback function you give it every `time` milliseconds. So as an example, if you used `window.setInterval(function() { console.log('Hi!'); }, 1500)`, it would log `Hi!` to the console every 1.5 seconds (1500ms).

In your case, you want to first load all the JSON, which you can do with AJAX. (I assume the objects in your JSON file are actually in an array, since the side-by-side objects you posted aren't actually valid JSON when they're like that.) The easiest modern approach is to use `fetch`, which would work like this (if your JSON file is located at `./mediaList.json`):

```
fetch('./mediaList.json')
.then(result => result.json())
.then(json => {
    // Your code here
});
```

Where I wrote `// Your code here`, you can access the parameter `json` and it will contain the entire JSON object from that file, for you to use however you want.

So what I'd suggest is you have a variable, such as `currentIndex`, that starts at 0. After you get your JSON with the above code, you start an interval that calls a function which renders the current object at the currentIndex, then increments currentIndex.

The tricky part is that each element is shown for a different amount of time. So for that to work, you need some way of connecting each element to its duration. I'd recommend that, if you need varying durations like that, you use `window.setTimeout` instead of `window.setInterval`. It does the same thing with the same parameters, except it only runs once after the time you specify rather than constantly repeating. You need to include the duration in each object, and then when your function runs, you'd take the duration from the current object and call `window.setTimeout` again with the current object's duration, so it'll only update after that time has passed.

Comment: Thanks a lot IceMetalPunk I'll try that, I really appreciate your help.